# Does $\det(A^2) = \det(A)*\det(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I've tried it with numbers and both operation don't equal each other,
while $\det(AB)$ equal $\det(A)*\det(B)$

$A$ = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&-2&1\\1&2&-1&0\\2&5&-6&4\\-2&-4&4&-1\end{bmatrix}

$\det(A)$ = -1

but $\det(A^2) = 535$

what I am doing wrong ?

---

EDIT : it does I made a calculation mistake

Comment: You should add what you have tried so that others can help you find and fix your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please include your attempt with numbers, because there's probably an error in your calculation. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: check again your calculation, how did you derived det(A)?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my calculations.

Comment: @RootOfMinusOne I've added a derivation by using the property that det doesn't change adding multimple of a row to Others row, in this way you can simplify a lot and avoid errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\;\det(A^n) =\left(\det (A)\right)^n\;$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357765/is-detan-left-det-a-rightn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is a theorem/property of determinant also known as [Binet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) and $\det(A^2)=\det(A)\cdot \det(A)$ is just a special case of $\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot \det(B)$ with $B=A$.

Indeed we find

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-8&12&-8\\1&1&2&-3\\-13&-32&43&-26\\4&12&-20&15\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\det(A^2)=\begin{vmatrix}-3&-8&12&-8\\1&1&2&-3\\-13&-32&43&-26\\4&12&-20&15\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}0&-5&18&-17\\1&1&2&-3\\0&-19&69&-65\\0&8&-28&27\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}0&-5&18&-17\\1&1&2&-3\\0&1&-3&3\\0&-2&8&-7\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}0&0&3&-2\\1&1&2&-3\\0&1&-3&3\\0&0&2&-1\end{vmatrix}=1$$

Comment: it should be a comment.

Comment: @Surb I've precisely answered to the OP. The problem is indeed that very often answers are posted as comment.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly computed the $\det A = -1$.

The square of $A$ is \begin{bmatrix}-3&-8&12&-8\\1&1&2&-3\\-13&-32&43&-26\\4&12&-20&15\end{bmatrix}
and its determinant is $1$.

So you either squared the matrix incorrectly, or computed the second determinant incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your answer using Wolfram Alpha.

It [agrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%5B%5B1,2,-2,1%5D,%5B1,2,-1,0%5D,%5B2,5,-6,4%5D,%5B-2,-4,4,-1%5D%5D) that $det(A)=-1$.

It [finds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1,2,-2,1%5D,%5B1,2,-1,0%5D,%5B2,5,-6,4%5D,%5B-2,-4,4,-1%5D%5D*%5B%5B1,2,-2,1%5D,%5B1,2,-1,0%5D,%5B2,5,-6,4%5D,%5B-2,-4,4,-1%5D%5D) that $$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-8&12&-8\\1&1&2&-3\\-13&-32&43&-26\\4&12&-20&15\end{bmatrix}$$

And it [confirms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+%5B%5B-3,-8,12,-8%5D,%5B1,1,2,-3%5D,%5B-13,-32,43,-26%5D,%5B4,12,-20,15%5D%5D) that $det(A^2)=1$.

Looking over the above, perhaps you can find the error in your hand calculations.